# Split the string by any of given delimiters

Tags: javascript

I have this ugly sentences separated with `||`.

```
const a = "they *have* a* car* sold. ||They* eat* the * good * stuff";
```

How can I split the given string by `*` or `||` signs so that we get this result:

```
['they', 'have','a', 'car', 'sold', 'they', 'eat', 'the ', 'good ', 'stuff'];
```

I don't mind spacing issues I want the split by this or that functionality.

Note: we can achieve this simply using a `map` but I wonder if there is a solution by regex or something!

Comment: It seems like you just want the `\w`ord characters: https://regex101.com/r/9HWuH2/1/

Comment: You can use `.split(/\W+/)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make it more gengeral, you may

- `.split()` by one or more consequent (`+` quantifier) non-alphabetic characters (`/[^a-z]/`),
- apply `.filter(Boolean)` to get rid of empty strings in resulting array (which may appear under certain circumstances)
- use `Array.prototype.map()` to apply lower-casing to each word (`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`)

```js
const src = "they *have* a* car* sold. ||They* eat* the * good * stuff",

      result = src
        .split(/[^a-z]+/i)
        .filter(Boolean)
        .map(w => w.toLowerCase())
      
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I think if you use `/[^a-z]+/i` you could remove the additional `filter(Boolean)` iteration ;)

Comment: @NickParsons : then result of `.split()` will contain empty strings

Comment: I get `["they","have","a","car","sold","They","eat","the","good","stuff"]` if I split it using `/[^a-z]+/i`, so no empty strings, but I guess you would get an empty string if a non-alphabetic character was at the start or end of the string doing it this way

Answer (score 3):

You could use [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) which will return you an array of matches found in the string for a given regex.

```js
const a = "they *have* a* car* sold. ||They* eat* the * good * stuff";

console.log(a.match(/\w+/g));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let a = "they *have* a* car* sold. ||They* eat* the * good * stuff";

a = a.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")
a = a.split(' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const a = "they *have* a* car* sold. ||They* eat* the * good * stuff";
let arr = a.split(/\*|\|\|/);
console.log(...arr);
```

Comment: Items of `arr` contain dots and spaces as opposed to expected output

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution without regex if you want to avoid them

```js
const a = "they *have* a* car* sold. ||They* eat* the * good * stuff";

function multisplit(input, ...splits) {
  input = [input]
  while (splits.length) {
    let splitter = splits.shift()
    input = input.flatMap(sub => sub.split(splitter))
  }
  return input.map(el => el.trim())
}

console.log(multisplit(a, "*", "||"))
```

Comment: The output contains extra spaces and dots as opposed to expected output.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov op said he don't mind about spacing issues, but I'll add a trim